# Asynchronus chunking in AS3?

Tags: flash

I found some code to break down process intensive loops so that screen rendering can still occur.

I've almost got it working - only thing is I have to keep pressing a 'Start' button to get through the whole process, rather than it doing it automatically - I'm not understanding the 'return' properly:

```
test_csv_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, testCSVFunc);

function testCSVFunc ( event : Event ) {

    for (var i:uint = 0; i < csv.data.length; i++) {        

        if (csv.data[i][colArtist] == '') {         

            csv.data[i][colArtist] = csv.data[i-1][colArtist];

        }       
    }

    enterFrame();
}


//pseudo code
var allowedTime = 1000/24 - 2 - 2;
var startTime = 0;
var savedIndex = 0;


function enterFrame() {

    startTime = getTimer();

    var i, n = csv.data.length;
    for (i=savedIndex; i<n; i++){

        if (getTimer() - startTime > allowedTime){
            savedIndex = i;
            return;
        }
        trace(i);
        finalCSV(csv.data[i]);
    }

    //complete();
    trace ('done');
}


function finalCSV ( file ) {    

    if (file[colTitle] != '') {             

        trace(file[colTitle]);
        csvHolder.csvText.appendText(file[colArtist]+' -- '+file[colTitle]+'\n');
    }

}
```

As it stands, enterFrame does work until the timer limit is reached, and then stops.  To get it to resume, I have to press the test_csv_btn to iterate through the next chunk, and so on until it's all done.

How do I get the process to continue automatically until completion?  It seems to return to testCSVFunc at the end of each chunk and stops.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are using is called "pseudo-threading", and you can find a number of generalized implementations on the internet.  You can find one that resembles Java threads in the [as3commons](http://code.google.com/p/as3-commons/source/browse/trunk/as3-commons-concurrency/src/main/actionscript/org/as3commons/concurrency/thread/PseudoThread.as) library, and / or check out [this tutorial](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/asyncoperations/) to learn about the basics.

Answer (score 0):

What the code does (on a high level) is this:

1. When you click the button, the input data is set up (`testCSVFunc()` - the loop makes sure that empty artist cells are filled with the previous row's artist cell).
2. Then it (`testCSVFunc()`) calls `enterFrame()`
3. `enterFrame()` calls finalCSV repeatedly, adding lines of "Artist -- Title" to a text field.
4. ... until the specified time has passed. I.e. 1000/**24** - 2 - 2 = approx. 38 msecs - which corresponds to slightly less than the duration of a frame at **24** frames per second. Not sure why "- 2 - 2", but the idea is to leave some time each frame for Flash to do other things (like rendering the stage).
5. When 38 msecs have been spent processing, it stops (the `return` statement) - and will do nothing more until you click again (at which point it will - by being called from `testCSVFunc()` - continue where it left off - at `savedIndex`). `testCSVFunc` will continue to process data, until `i < n` is no longer true - i.e., when there are no more items left in the CSV.

I'm guessing the idea is that testCSVFunc should only be called once. It sets up all the data (calling it twice adds the same data to the "todo list" once more). Then finalCSV is supposed to process that data and add it to the text field.

Which means `enterFrame()` isn't supposed to be called directly by testCSVFunc (which is triggered by the click) - it's meant to be called once every frame (hence the name), until all the data has been processed.

I.e. rather than calling `enterFrame()`, you set it up as an ENTER_FRAME event handler:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
```

In that way, when clicking, the "thread" will start, and `enterFrame()` will be executed each frame.

Remember to add an `event:Event` parameter to the `enterFrame()` declaration - even though you don't use it. Otherwise you'll get an error about the missing parameter:

```
function enterFrame(event:Event):void {
   ...    
}
```

When done processing (when the loop no longer iterates, because `i < n` is no longer true), it would be a good idea to disable the event handler again, i.e.:

```
// done
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
trace('done');
```

Otherwise it will keep calling the "worker method", even though it has no more work to do.

All in all, this means that each frame, most of the frame time (38 msecs) will be spent filling out the text field, after which the rendering of the stage can execute. I'd probably set `allowedTime` somewhat lower than that.

As weltraumpirat says, there are generalized implementations that are probably more efficient and likely to take care of Flash's idiosyncracies, but as an experiment in working out how "pseudo-threading" actually works, it's a good learning exercise.

Comment: Wow - you should be a teacher TheKaneda - that made is soooooooooo clear.  THANK YOU!!!  I'm going to now try to incorporate it into an external .as file, as soon as I figure out how to let an external as file update a text field on the stage.  Research time!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [workers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html)? They allow to create simultaneously executing threads without workarounds.